# getting shards under a mongos

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a `MongoConnection` to a mongos instance. Mongos internally connects to three shards. Is there any way using which I can get the individual connection each shards or at least get the info on the shards so that I can create new connections ?

I have looked at the `MongoConnection` class and didn't find anything related to mongos.
http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/1.3.1/Mongo/Connection.html

Mongo version 2.2 and MongoDriver 1.3.1 and language ruby

Eg:
Mongos is a `localhost:27107`
which has shards at 214.187.112.113:27107 , 209.117.116.103:27107  114.117.162.123:27107

Now My `MongoConnection` variable has connection to `localhost:27107` is there a way from this connection I can create connections to individual shards @ 214.187.11.113 etc

Comment: Not really clear on exactly what you want to do. Clearly you want to code something, but can you clarify exactly what you expect that code to do?

Comment: @NeilLunn added more info to the question

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB cluster comes with 3 types of components
1.) Query Router(a *mongos* instance)
2.) Config server (a mongod instance
3.) Sharding servers (mongod instances)

Mongos is a sharding service provided by MomgoDB.
Mongo shard servers gets registered to config server via mongos.

```
sh.addShard( "mongo-shard-1:27017" )
sh.addShard( "mongo-shard-2:27017" )
```

When any request (read/write) comes to mongos, the mongos first gets shard information from config server and then serves that request by forwarding it to the appropriate sharding server(s).

As each shard server is also running mongod, you can connect to it directly but then it will serve as an independent MongoDB instance and will not be a part of cluster.

if you want to control sharding you can do it as follow.
https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mongodb/build-database-clusters-with-mongodb